# Why was my flag accepted, but no action was taken?

Tags: support, user-profile

I flagged [This Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/275380/142044) for mod attention stating that the users profile picture wan inappropriate. It got accepted. And no action was taken. Can someone tell me why this happened? Or is the mod still deciding?
Look closely, I mean ***CLOSELY*** 
 At the picture. And you will see what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Also the < u > in the text isn't working on mobile

Comment: Has modetator left any comment? Could you also say what comment did *you* left?

Comment: @nicael http://i.stack.imgur.com/SXibv.jpg

Comment: Maybe the mod simply thought, as I did, that you were over-reacting :/ If you say "I find this offensive", no body can say "that is false". Its your opinion, and your entitle to it. But ultimately, not everyone may agree. You might not agree, for example, that you *are* over reacting. But it seems you went far out of your way to chase back up the flag, and then deliberately locate that users profile to check up on the mod who actioned it. The word in question has a historical meaning, and you could just as easily hear it watching a movie rated PG-13.

Comment: If its considered suitable for under 13s, it should be considered *acceptable*, given that we have a higher age restriction.

Comment: Incidentally, it appears they have been reset to identicon now.

Comment: @Unionhawk then should I delete the question ?

Comment: /shrug? Basically the answer is that sometimes a mod might decide that no action is required even if a flag is helpful. I don't know in this particular case.